# jquery-tmpl - template function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, jquery-templates

The following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function getBooks() {
        var query = "ajax.php?do=allbooks";
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "jsonp",
                url: query,
                jsonp: "callback",
                success: showBooks
            });
    }

    function showBooks(data) {
    $("#bookTmpl").tmpl(data, { 
        getName: function() {
          return 'bla';
        }
    }).appendTo( "#test" ); 
    }

    getBooks();
});
```

What I am trying to do is use the getName()-function in my template.

Let's pretend my template looks like this:

```
<script id="bookTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li>
    ${title} by ${author}<br />
    Rating: ${rating} -> ${getName()}
    </li>
</script>
```

What do I have to change to make it work? Right now, the function isn't even executed. Everything else works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to adjust the call a bit, change this:

```
${getName()}
```

To this:

```
${this.getName()}
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/k6BDJ/).

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching the `error: fn` callback in `$.ajax` and see what might be wrong. Perhaps the JSON is malformed (you can check that with jsonlint.org). If the `success: fn` isn't even being called, something is wrong (404, JSON parse error etc.).

Also, JSONP might be a bit overkill if you're requesting JSON from the same domain (e.g. try something like `$.getJSON` or `dataType: 'json'`)

Comment: Sorry, I somewhat misread your question. Does your template work (except for the method)?